# Client validation of multiple widgets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a submit button whose enablement state depends on several other widgets' state; and I can't come up with a client side solution in Google Apps Script to do the validation.

For example, take three checkboxes. The submit button should be enabled iff (if-and-only-if) at least one checkbox is enabled.

I know I could do this with server side validation but there shouldn't be any need for something this simple. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It perfectly possible to write client side handlers that depend on multiple widgets' states, as you can just chain many `validateX` calls on a single handler. The problem here is just that `clientHandlers` cannot validate checkboxes state.

I have opened an issue regarding this problem, you may want to star it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it:

[Issue 2220: UiApp handler validateValue of checkbox](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2220)

Anyway, it is possible to workaround this, and I'll just to show you that it is possible to have handlers depending on multiple widgets value, but this code will be much simpler when issue 2220 is solved:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Checkbox Test');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel(),
      noChecked = app.createClientHandler(),
      button = app.createButton('Test').setEnabled(false);

  for( var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
    var cb1 = app.createCheckBox('cb'+i),
        cb2 = app.createCheckBox('cb'+i).setVisible(false),
        tb = app.createTextBox().setValue('false').setVisible(false);
    cb1.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(cb2).setValue(true).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setVisible(false).forTargets(tb).setText('true'));
    cb2.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(cb1).setValue(false).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setVisible(false).forTargets(tb).setText('false'));
    cb1.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(button).setEnabled(true));
    cb2.addClickHandler(noChecked.validateMatches(tb,'false'));
    panel.add(cb1).add(cb2).add(tb);
  }
  noChecked.forTargets(button).setEnabled(false);  

  return app.add(panel.add(button));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Took me a minute to get my head sync with the logic. That certainly shows that it is possible, though you must agree it feels clunky. Even if there is a way to validate Checkbox state (as per issue 2220), which would remove the need for the text boxes, the extra Checkbox still doubles the number widgets. I'm starting to feel that for any UIs with anything other than trivial logic HtmlService is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Henrique, I spent an hour on this yesterday and came very close of your code (also playing with dual checkBoxes) but I failed to get it working.... you did it ! Thanks for that, I'm going to copy that in code snippets collection for future use ;-)

Comment: @Daniel if issue 2220 is fixed there will be no need for the extra checkboxes. We'll be able to add two handlers on the same checkbox, one that validates for ticking and the `noChecked` handler.

Answer (score 0):

ClientHandlers are intentionally simple. You can do arbitrary code with ServerHandlers and the speed difference should be relatively small. Otherwise, yes, this is by design and if you need more complicated client logic you need to use HtmlService.

The tradeoff between UiApp and HtmlService related to how we guarantee that you can't serve malicious code from a script. UiApp code uses simple builder patterns that are limiting but definitely safe, while HtmlService uses complex sandboxing to achieve that goal, with tradeoffs of not working on older browsers and some other limitations.

This specific use case sounds workable in UiApp, if I understand you correctly. If you want an example of a show/hide button that flips, here is one:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var label = app.createLabel("I am a toggleable widget").setVisible(false);
  var show = app.createButton("show");
  var hide = app.createButton("hide").setVisible(false);
  show.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler()
      .forTargets(label, hide).setVisible(true).forTargets(show).setVisible(false));
  hide.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler()
      .forTargets(label, hide).setVisible(false).forTargets(show).setVisible(true));
  return app.add(show).add(hide).add(label);
}
```

Basically, use 2 buttons and flip the visibility of the button too.

Checkboxes are in fact validated - but it is their text that is validated, not their value:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var check = app.createCheckBox();
check.setText("foo").addClickHandler(
    app.createServerHandler("clicked").validateMatches(check, "foo"));
return app.add(check);
```

The issue tracker request is reasonable though.

Comment: Checkboxes are validated by their text (label), but that is no help in determining its state with a validator, it can only help determine which checkbox was clicked.

Comment: Which is totally useless. If you don't want a handler to run on a given checkbox, just do not add it. Validating the state (i.e. checked/unchecked) is what matters.

Comment: Yup. It's not really intentional behavior so much as we just built the validators to always validate "text" fields. It can occasionally be useful but I agree it's not really what you want.